# Calling bash script inside AWS CodeBuild: script could not be found

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to run a small bash script inside my CodeBuild process as per the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-cmd.html) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/b4y3xr/running_bashsh_on_codebuild/).

`deploy.sh` can be found in the `src/` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd=$PWD

for dir in */ ; do
  target="$pwd/${dir%/}"
  cd "$target"
  npm install
  sls deploy && sls s3deploy
done
```

buildspec file:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
    - cd backend/functions/src
    - npm install serverless
  build:
    commands:
    - ls
    - ./deploy.sh
```

after the `ls` command above in the logs, I can see that `deploy.sh` is there in the current directory.

Error:

> /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: ./deploy.sh: not found

I've also tried using the command `/bin/bash deploy.sh` but this results in another error:

> deploy.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
>
> deploy.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
>
> deploy.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
>
> deploy.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
>
> deploy.sh: line 8: `for dir in */ ; do

Comment: Did you make the file under Windows? Convert to DOS `\r` line endings to unix.

Comment: @WalterA nice catch. it was written in WSL, changing from CRLF to LF fixed the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(First written as a comment, it solved the problem)

The files were made in Windows.
Change CRLF to LF and the `\r` is gone.

Comment: had a sort a like issue in azure app servvice, but did also did the trick there, THX

Answer (score 2):

The first answer by Walter A worked for me, this is what i did .

1. Opened the file in VS Code
2. At bottom left corner for Select End Of Line Sequence it showed CRLF
   [image]
3. clicked on CRLF and selected LF
   [image]
4. Uploaded the file to github and it started working.